# Rename the current [snowflake-data-warehouse] to [snowflake-cloud-data-platform] and merge all to same and pre-existing tag and url redirects

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have a request from Snowflake to please change the names of the following tags: 
[snowflake-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-warehouse) to [snowflake-cloud-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform)

Please leave the snowflake tag forwarding to this main tag. Can we create a new tag and merge the current snowflake-data-warehouse tag, and still have the URLS [snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake), [snowflake-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-warehouse) and [snowflake-cloud-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform) pointing to the same queue?

Do requests like this ensure that anyone that is ‘subscribed’ or has filters for these tags still see all the content in that tag?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen the help center guidance on the topic, so I'll just post here: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Comment: Hi Heretic, thank you for the guidance, I will keep that in mind. I am aware of the second article.

Answer (score 1):

Since there were no objections to this so far, I went ahead and changed [snowflake-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-warehouse) to [snowflake-cloud-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform).

[snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake), [snowflake-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-warehouse) and [snowflake-cloud-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform) are still considered synonyms to the new tag and should point there normally. [snowflake-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-warehouse) is also a synonym now and also points there.