# Rename the current [snowflake-cloud-data-platform] to [snowflake-data-cloud] and merge all to the same and pre-existing tag and URL redirects

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

We have a request from [Snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_Inc.) to please change the names of the following tags:
[snowflake-cloud-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform) to [snowflake-data-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-cloud)

Please leave the snowflake tag forwarding to this main tag. Can we create a new tag and merge the current snowflake-cloud-data-platform tag, and still have the URLs [snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake), [snowflake-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-warehouse) and [snowflake-cloud-data-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform) and [snowflake-data-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snowflake-data-cloud) pointing to the same queue?

Do requests like this ensure that anyone that is ‘subscribed’ or has filters for these tags still see all the content in that tag?

--

Additional note: Hi! I [work for Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/snowflake-cloud-data-platform/topusers) and this request is [similar to this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394797/rename-the-current-snowflake-data-warehouse-to-snowflake-cloud-data-platform) a year ago; hence I followed the same pattern to submit it.